# Copy a hidden element with clone() - better way?

Tags: jquery, clone, hidden, element

I've managed to copy a hidden element (`$("#products-area").find(".mysets-area")`) by checking the state of the element, temporarily showing it and then hide it again after cloning.

**But I may think there would be a better to achieve this?**

```
var stateVisible = $("#products-area").find(".mysets-area").css("display");
if (stateVisible == 'none') {
    $("#products-area").find(".mysets-area").show();
}

$("#user-dialog .open-mysets").html($("#products-area").find(".mysets-area").clone());                

if (stateVisible == 'none') {
    $("#products-area").find(".mysets-area").hide();
}
```

Comment: why ask us, you are the 'bestprogrammerintheworld'

Comment: That's the reason why he's the best: he asks if doesn't know :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not clone the element while it's hidden and show the new element?

```
var orig = $("#products-area").find(".mysets-area");
var cloned = $(orig).clone().show();
$("#user-dialog .open-mysets").html(cloned);
```

Shown in this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaypeagi/qCwJA/2/

Comment: Forgive me for late feedback. I don't know why this didn't work for me before but it obviously do work and thank you a lot!!!